# How do I check via batch script whether VCBUILD failed or suceeded

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, batch-file

I assumed `%ERRORLEVEL%` would be non-zero if the build failed, but that is not the case.

Comment: I know little about VCBUILD, but if it doesn't set ERRORLEVEL then you could try parsing the output, something like `vcbuild | find "failed" && set failed=1`.

Comment: That is a great idea, unfortunately, it poses a couple of problems. One, I don't know how to perform `FIND` on the console output (not sure if it is possible). I can get around that by outputting to a file and performing `FIND` in that, but then if the build fails, I only have access to the console output which won't have the output from `VSBuild`. I can get around that as well by outputting whatever is in the file to the console once VSBuild finishes, but then since some builds take long, real-time console output is out of the question (at least to my knowledge) :(

Comment: You can apply `FIND` to the console output by using the `|` symbol: `vcbuild parameters | find "whatever"`. It is possible that `vcbuild` outputs the fail message to the so called *standard error* device (which is different from the *standard output*, even though also displays on the console), in which case you'd need to modify the command line like this: `vcbuild parameters 2>&1 | find "…"`. Again, I would be more certain if I knew more about the `vcbuild` utility.

Comment: @Andriy: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I did something similar, so if you put your answer, I will check it as correct and add my own explanation in the question as an `EDIT` (you may wish to add that in your answer as well)

Comment: My suggestion was rather a guess, and even though I knew what I was suggesting, I wasn't quite sure that it would really help in your situation. You, on the other hand, have done something that actually solved you problem (if I understand you correctly). If you posted your own report as an answer and accepted it, it would be, in my opinion, more helpful for other people who might later come across this post in search for a solution to a similar problem, than what I might post as a guess. I'm sure it would be absolutely fair, and I'm quite content with the fact that a solution has been found.

Comment: Are you shure about that %ERRORLEVEL% not being set ? MSBuild sets it. I only have Visual Studio 2010 to test. Can you add your batch file that calls vcbuild to your question ?

Comment: @ixe013: Yes, MSBUILD sets it but not VCBUILD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks over at the open source BlueCove project have [a batch file that checks the error level of vcbuild](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/source/browse/trunk/bluecove/build-native-intelbth.cmd). It basically goes like this :

1. Make shure `vcvars32.bat` was called
2. `vcbuild /u /rebuild myproject.sln "%CONFIGURATION%|Win32"`
3. `@if errorlevel 1 goto errormark`

If it doesn't help you, please update your question with the batch file that gives you trouble. Maybe your out of luck and a batch file named vcbuild.bat is called before the real vcbuild.exe ?

Comment: I have seen quite a few repositories that use errorLevel in their builds and when I encountered the error for the first time, that's what I did (look into how other people are handling it). I will post the batch file soon. I have solved the original problem but in a very convoluted way. I will check to see the role of `vcvars32.bat` in all this. Thanks for the link! (+1)